# What does 1 stands for in .ps1 PowerShell file extention?

Tags: powershell

It's obvious that p -> Power, s -> Shell, but what 1 means? And why not call it `.pss` for Power Shell Script?

Comment: .pss is already over-used. Presumably they didn't want to add to the confusion.

Comment: the theme is sh -> bash/dash/ash/ksh/zsh/csh/mksh/... and psh, but [psh is unavailable and neither is ps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12107462/995714). [Why ".PS1" file extension for PS scripts?](https://www.vistax64.com/threads/why-ps1-file-extension-for-ps-scripts.212073/)

Answer (score 9):

Presumably, although I have no documentation to back it up, it's because the 1 was for PS v1.  Powershell v2 scripts were supposed to use the extension .ps2 but Microsoft dropped the idea before the release of PS v2, thus the .ps1 extension stuck.

Comment: Adding to this, .ps2, .ps2xml, and .psc2 are all still valid powershell file extensions. There is an even longer list of other extensions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604621/what-are-the-different-powershell-file-types

Comment: "Valid file extension" is such a Windows thing to say :D

Comment: Some pretty conclusive info from Microsoft here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/ctp-versioning/